# Asp.Net Core with Keycloak

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, keycloak

I am trying to use Keycloak auth services to use with ASP.NET Core 3.1 application, I went through below links and none of them were useful, reason being obsolete

https://medium.com/@xavier.hahn/asp-net-core-angular-openid-connect-using-keycloak-6437948c008

Also, I tried couple of sample application hosted on git

https://github.com/Gimly/SampleNetCoreAngularKeycloak

https://github.com/ewertb/ASP-.NET-Core-Web-API-KeyCloak

Comment: So what is your specific problem? Here is a document you can refer to:https://github.com/vip32/aspnetcore-keycloak

Comment: Problem is-If I give [Authorize] on controller, its giving 401 Unauthorized error,if I remove [Authorize] attribute,application runs(quite expected behavior). The link above mentioned by you,I am concerned only with Angular application,so I removed all the unwanted application (except required file refs) and ran, it ended up saying "Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'".Then I ran nmp install from VS2019 NPM console & getting error "npm:npm WARN saveError ENOENT:no such file or directory, open \..\..\aspnetcore-keycloak-master\aspnetcore-keycloak-master\package.json"

Comment: I would want to help on this issue but it seems to be too broad for now. If your issue is on the [Authorize] attribute on the ASP.NET controller then your http request from the Angular application should satisfy the authorization needs such as an Authorization header. This varies per configuration on the ASP.NET like OAuth2, JToken, etc. If you started removing files and then encountered an error that's on you. You should not randomly remove packages if you are not sure. Better identify your real problem first.

Comment: Thanks, I have made a decent progress on upgrading from 2.X to 3.X and authentication is working fine. I am planning to upoad the modified code on git soon.